# Finding the maximum value in a 24h period SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, max, dt

In need of some help :)

So I have a table of records with the following columns:

Key (PK, FK, int)
DT (smalldatetime)
Value (real)

The DT is a datetime for every half hour of the day with an associated value

E.g.

```
Key       DT                       VALUE
1000      2010-01-01 08:00:00      80
1000      2010-01-01 08:30:00      75
1000      2010-01-01 09:00:00      100
```

I need to find the max value and associated DT for every 24 hour period. for a particular key and date range

Currently I have:

```
    SELECT CAST(LEFT([DT],11) as smalldatetime) as 'DATE'
          ,max([VALUE]) as 'MAX_HH'


FROM TABLE 1

  WHERE DT > '6-nov-2016' and [KEY] = '1000'
  GROUP BY CAST(LEFT([DT],11) as smalldatetime)
  ORDER BY 'DATE'
```

But this returns the max values for the date e.g.

```
Key       DT                       VALUE
1000      2010-01-01 00:00:00      100
```

Any ideas on how to pull the full DT ?

Thanks guys!

Comment: cast DT to `date` instead of taking the left 11 chars

Comment: Can you show the result you're expecting to get? I don't really understand your question...

Comment: Sorry, The expected outcome should be the full date time not just the date. For the example above it would give the DT 2010-01-01 09:00:00 instead of 2010-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @HoneyBadger That would return me the date but not the associated timestamp for the value unfortunately. Thank you for the response though :)

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you have to make a subquery as I suggested, and join it back to the table on max value. Or use windowed functions if your dbms supports them.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks for getting back, I'm not sure what the subquery would look like. I was playing around before I posted but wasn't quite there. I've never joined back from a subquery before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damien's answer is very good, if you can't (or want) to use windowed function, try this:

```
SELECT      T1.*
FROM        TABLE_1 AS T1
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT CAST([DT] as date) as 'DATE'
                ,       MAX([VALUE]) as 'MAX_HH'
                FROM    TABLE_1
                WHERE   DT > '6-nov-2016' and [KEY] = '1000'
                GROUP BY CAST([DT] as date)
            ) AS MAX_DT
        ON  MAX_DT.[DATE] = CAST(T1.[DT] as date)
        AND T1.VALUE = MAX_DT.MAX_HH
WHERE       DT > '6-nov-2016' and [KEY] = '1000'
ORDER BY DT
```

By the way, it's best not to use reserved keywords as object names (i.e. `date`)

Comment: Genius! Works perfectly, Thank you everyone! Life savers :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a database with support for windowed functions, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` (or `RANK` if you want to support/pull in values that are tied for first place):

```
declare @t table ([Key] int not null , DT smalldatetime not null, Value int not null)
insert into @t([Key],DT,VALUE) values
(1000,'2010-01-01T08:00:00',80 ),
(1000,'2010-01-01T08:30:00',75 ),
(1000,'2010-01-01T09:00:00',100)

;With Numbered as (
    select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key],CAST(DT as date) ORDER BY Value desc) as rn
    from @t
)
select * from Numbered
where rn=1
```